# Can the k-nearest neighbor algorithm tell you how many clusters there are among predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour

I recently did a short course on machine learning in R and found the k-means and k-nearest neighbor techniques extremely interesting.

Forgive my naivete if this is all wrong, but it seems like the drawback of k-means is that you need to know in advance how many clusters you want to extract from among the data.

What I want to know is **does the k-nearest neighbor algorithm tell you how many clusters it uses to make its predictions**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is a clustering (unsupervised) algorithm, but KNN is a classification/regression algorithm (supervised). KNN doesn't cluster data, it looks at the neighbouring points and assigns the target variable according to them. In that, you need specify a K as well.

Comment: Thank you @gunes. Do you know of any techniques where the model estimates the number of clusters? I suppose this is the sort of thing Principal Components analysis is good for.